# Return value in dataframe based on row index, column reference

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

My goal is to compare each value from the column "year" against the appropriate column year (i.e. 1999, 2000). I then want to return the corresponding value from the corresponding column. For example, for Afghanistan (first row), year 2004, I want to find the column named "2004" and return the value from the row that contains afghanistan.

Here is the table. For reference this table is the result of a sql join between educational attainment in a single defined year and a table for gdp per country for years 1999 - 2010. My ultimate goal is to return the gdp from the year that the educational data is from.

```
country year    men_ed_yrs  women_ed_yrs    total_ed_yrs    1999    2000    2001    2002    2003    2004    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009    2010
0   Afghanistan 2004    11  5   8   NaN NaN 2461666315  4128818042  4583648922  5285461999  6.275076e+09    7.057598e+09    9.843842e+09    1.019053e+10    1.248694e+10    1.593680e+10
1   Albania 2004    11  11  11  3414760915  3632043908  4060758804  4435078648  5746945913  7314865176  8.158549e+09    8.992642e+09    1.070101e+10    1.288135e+10    1.204421e+10    1.192695e+10
2   Algeria 2005    13  13  13  48640611686 54790060513 54744714110 56760288396 67863829705 85324998959 1.030000e+11    1.170000e+11    1.350000e+11    1.710000e+11    1.370000e+11    1.610000e+11
3   Andorra 2008    11  12  11  1239840270  1401694156  1484004617  1717563533  2373836214  2916913449  3.248135e+09    3.536452e+09    4.010785e+09    4.001349e+09    3.649863e+09    3.346317e+09
4   Anguilla    2008    11  11  11  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

My approach so far is:

```
for value in df_combined_column_named['year']: #loops through each year in year column
    if value in df_combined_column_named.columns
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`df.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
In [62]: df.loc[df['country']=='Afghanistan', '2004'].item()
Out[62]: 5285461999.0
```

`df.loc[rows, columns]` can accept a boolean Series (such as `df['country']=='Afghanistan'`) for `rows` and a column label (such as `'2004'`) for `columns`. It will return the values for rows where the boolean Series is True and in the specified column.

In general this can be more than one value, so a Series is returned. However, in this case, there is only one value in the Series. So to obtain just the value, call the [`item` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.item.html).

---

Note it is unclear from the posted string representation of `df` whether the numeric column labels are strings are integers. If the numeric column labels are integers, then you would need to use

```
df.loc[df['country']=='Afghanistan', 2004].item()
```

(with no quotation marks around `2004`).

---

If you are going to make a lot of "queries" of this form, you make wish to set the `country` column as the index:

```
df = df.set_index('country')
```

Then you could access the value in the cell whose row label is `'Afghanistan'` and whose column label is `'2004'` using [`get_value`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.get_value.html):

```
In [65]: df.get_value('Afghanistan', '2004')
Out[65]: 5285461999.0
```

Comment: thanks, @unutbu. I ended up using the second method you suggested, but I'm sure I will find a use for you first suggestion, too!

Comment: HI @unutbu, I updated the question. the problem I am facing now is finding the appropriate index value as a variable. Your expertise is much appreciated!

Comment: You are asking an interesting question which deserves an entirely different answer than the one I posted. Please revert this question and ask a new one; I'll be glad to offer a suggestion there. (Note, changing the goal post on questions invalidates work spent writing answers and can be demoralizing to answerers.)

Comment: apologies. I'm fairly new to all this. I've reverted the original questions. Here's the new one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416924/iterate-through-df-column-and-return-value-in-dataframe-based-on-row-index-colu . Your thoughts are much appreciated!