# iterate through df column and return value in dataframe based on row index, column reference

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

My goal is to compare each value from the column "year" against the appropriate column year (i.e. 1999, 2000). I then want to return the corresponding value from the corresponding column. For example, for Afghanistan (first row), year 2004, I want to find the column named "2004" and return the value from the row that contains afghanistan.

Here is the table. For reference this table is the result of a sql join between educational attainment in a single defined year and a table for gdp per country for years 1999 - 2010. My ultimate goal is to return the gdp from the year that the educational data is from.

```
country year    men_ed_yrs  women_ed_yrs    total_ed_yrs    1999    2000    2001    2002    2003    2004    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009    2010
0   Afghanistan 2004    11  5   8   NaN NaN 2461666315  4128818042  4583648922  5285461999  6.275076e+09    7.057598e+09    9.843842e+09    1.019053e+10    1.248694e+10    1.593680e+10
1   Albania 2004    11  11  11  3414760915  3632043908  4060758804  4435078648  5746945913  7314865176  8.158549e+09    8.992642e+09    1.070101e+10    1.288135e+10    1.204421e+10    1.192695e+10
2   Algeria 2005    13  13  13  48640611686 54790060513 54744714110 56760288396 67863829705 85324998959 1.030000e+11    1.170000e+11    1.350000e+11    1.710000e+11    1.370000e+11    1.610000e+11
3   Andorra 2008    11  12  11  1239840270  1401694156  1484004617  1717563533  2373836214  2916913449  3.248135e+09    3.536452e+09    4.010785e+09    4.001349e+09    3.649863e+09    3.346317e+09
4   Anguilla    2008    11  11  11  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

gdp_ed_list = []
for value in df_combined_column_named['year']: #loops through each year in year column
        if value in df_combined_column_named.columns: #compares year to column names
            idx = df_combined_column_named[df_combined_column_named['year'][value]].index.tolist() #supposed to get the index associated with value
            gdp_ed = df_combined_column_named.get_value(idx, value) #get the value of the cell found at idx, value
            gdp_ed_list.append(gdp_ed) #append to a list
```

Currently, my code is getting stuck at the index.list() section. It is returning the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-361acb97edd4> in <module>()
      2 for value in df_combined_column_named['year']: #loops through each year in year column
      3     if value in df_combined_column_named.columns: #compares year to column names
----> 4         idx = df_combined_column_named[df_combined_column_named['year'][value]].index.tolist()
      5         gdp_ed = df_combined_column_named.get_value(idx, value)
      6         gdp_ed_list.append(gdp_ed)
KeyError: u'2004'
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to match the value in the `year` column to column labels and then extract the value in the corresponding cells. You could do that by looping through the rows (see below) but I think it would be not be the fastest way. 
Instead, you could use [`pd.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) to coalesce the columns with year-like labels into a single column, say, `year_col`:

```
In [38]: melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['country', 'year', 'men_ed_yrs', 'women_ed_yrs', 'total_ed_yrs'], var_name='year_col')

In [39]: melted
Out[39]: 
        country  year  men_ed_yrs  women_ed_yrs  total_ed_yrs year_col         value  
0   Afghanistan  2004          11             5             8     1999            NaN   
1       Albania  2004          11            11            11     1999   3.414761e+09   
2       Algeria  2005          13            13            13     1999   4.864061e+10   
3       Andorra  2008          11            12            11     1999   1.239840e+09   
4      Anguilla  2008          11            11            11     1999            NaN   
5   Afghanistan  2004          11             5             8     2000            NaN
...
```

The benefit of "melting" the DataFrame in this way is that 
now you would have both `year` and `year_col` columns. *The values you are looking for are in the rows where `year` equals `year_col`*. And that is easy to obtain by using `.loc`:

```
In [41]: melted.loc[melted['year'] == melted['year_col']]
Out[41]: 
        country  year  men_ed_yrs  women_ed_yrs  total_ed_yrs year_col  \
25  Afghanistan  2004          11             5             8     2004   
26      Albania  2004          11            11            11     2004   
32      Algeria  2005          13            13            13     2005   
48      Andorra  2008          11            12            11     2008   
49     Anguilla  2008          11            11            11     2008   

           value  
25  5.285462e+09  
26  7.314865e+09  
32  1.030000e+11  
48  4.001349e+09  
49           NaN
```

---

Thus, you could use

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
nan = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'1999': [nan, 3414760915.0, 48640611686.0, 1239840270.0, nan],
 '2000': [nan, 3632043908.0, 54790060513.0, 1401694156.0, nan],
 '2001': [2461666315.0, 4060758804.0, 54744714110.0, 1484004617.0, nan],
 '2002': [4128818042.0, 4435078648.0, 56760288396.0, 1717563533.0, nan],
 '2003': [4583648922.0, 5746945913.0, 67863829705.0, 2373836214.0, nan],
 '2004': [5285461999.0, 7314865176.0, 85324998959.0, 2916913449.0, nan],
 '2005': [6275076000.0, 8158549000.0, 103000000000.0, 3248135000.0, nan],
 '2006': [7057598000.0, 8992642000.0, 117000000000.0, 3536452000.0, nan],
 '2007': [9843842000.0, 10701010000.0, 135000000000.0, 4010785000.0, nan],
 '2008': [10190530000.0, 12881350000.0, 171000000000.0, 4001349000.0, nan],
 '2009': [12486940000.0, 12044210000.0, 137000000000.0, 3649863000.0, nan],
 '2010': [15936800000.0, 11926950000.0, 161000000000.0, 3346317000.0, nan],
 'country': ['Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'Andorra', 'Anguilla'],
 'men_ed_yrs': [11, 11, 13, 11, 11],
 'total_ed_yrs': [8, 11, 13, 11, 11],
 'women_ed_yrs': [5, 11, 13, 12, 11],
 'year': ['2004', '2004', '2005', '2008', '2008']})

melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['country', 'year', 'men_ed_yrs', 'women_ed_yrs', 
                              'total_ed_yrs'], var_name='year_col')
result = melted.loc[melted['year'] == melted['year_col']]
print(result)
```

---

*Why was a `KeyError` raised*:

The `KeyError` is being raised by `df_combined_column_named['year'][value]`. Suppose `value` is `'2004'`. Then `df_combined_column_named['year']` is a Series containing string representations of years and indexed by integers (like 0, 1, 2, ...). `df_combined_column_named['year'][value]` fails because it attempts to index this Series with the string `'2004'` which is not in the integer index.

---

Alternatively, here is another way to achieve the goal by looping through the rows using [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html). This is perhaps simpler to understand, but in general using `iterrows` is [slow compared to other column-based Pandas-centric methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25918379/190597):

```
data = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    data.append((row['country'], row['year'], row[row['year']]))
result = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['country', 'year', 'value'])
print(result)
```

prints

```
       country  year         value
0  Afghanistan  2004  5.285462e+09
1      Albania  2004  7.314865e+09
2      Algeria  2005  1.030000e+11
3      Andorra  2008  4.001349e+09
4     Anguilla  2008           NaN
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to provide both these solutions! I've successfully implemented the second one. Now, I'm working my way through each line to make sure I understand the first solution.